# Recursion with tuple types

Tags: haskell, recursion, tuples

I've been struggling with a function that is supposed to return a nested tuple. Specifically, the typing of the function is giving me a lot of issues. A simplified version is below:

```
tupfnc :: ?????
tupfnc [a] = (a,()) --
tupfnc (a:as) = (a,tupfnc as)
```

The idea is to take in an list of items (say `[0,1,5,3]`) and nest them into a tuple like this: `(0,(1,(5,(3,()))))`.

My inital thought was to go with a declaration like so:

```
tupfnc :: [a] -> (a,b)
```

However, the third line (of this example) throws this error:

```
Solver.hs:56:17: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, b)’
                  with actual type ‘[(a, (a, b0))]’
    • In the expression: [(a, tupfnc as)]
      In an equation for ‘tupfnc’: tupfnc (a : as) = [(a, tupfnc as)]
    • Relevant bindings include
        as :: [a] 
        a :: a 
        tupfnc :: [a] -> (a, b)
```

Comment: There are several things off here. First of all, your "array" (which is a list) will always contain the _same_ type. You cannot have `[0,1,'a',3]`, since `'a'` is not an `Int`. Next, you return a list or a tuple, but their types differ, so that's not possible either. And last, but not least, the types `(a,b)` and `(a,(a,b))` differ, unless `b ~ (a,b)` and therefore infinite. You would have to use a `data InPair a = Stop | InPair a (InPair a)` to create that, but now you're back to a list. Are you looking for type-level inhomogeneous lists?

Comment: My bad, my head wasn't on straight when writing the question. I've edited it to be more correct. The list's items are all supposed to be of the same type. Your comment about b~(a,b) was more where I was looking towards. I don't know how to define a function that returns an infinite type (is that what they are called?).  I'll also have a look at type-level inhomogeneous lists

Comment: Even with the edit, you still return `(a, ())` and `[(a, …)]`. You return a list or a tuple, but those are different types. This seems like a XY problem. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Bugger. I mean to only return tuples -- I've edited it again. Sorry for messing up so terribly. It isn't actually an XY problem, I do want to know how to go through tuples with recursion (i.e. finding proper typing for tupfunc) -- I just horrifically butchered my attempted SSCCE implementation.

Comment: you want variable-length tuples, unfortunately haskell doesn't support that, that's why `fst` function works only on pairs even though it should work with any tuple regardless of size

Comment: and Thomas is right, it's an XY problem unless you're just trying things, if there is a real problem post it, probably you'll want to return a list instead of tuples

Comment: Hmm...you're right. There is a real problem but it's a large part of an assignment so I don't think it's really appropriate to post it here. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible unless you have type-level informations about the length of the list. Imagining a variant of lists called `Vector` in which that where the case, you could do the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, PolyKinds, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators #-}

-- | Peano natural numbers
data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- Just for convenience...
type N0 = Z
type N1 = S N0
type N2 = S N1
type N3 = S N2
type N4 = S N3
type N5 = S N4
type N6 = S N5
type N7 = S N6
type N8 = S N7
type N9 = S N8

-- | Equivalent to a list, but carries information about its length with it
data Vector (n :: Nat) a where
  Nil    :: Vector Z a
  (:-)   :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a

infixr 5 :-
```

Now, we can define a type family that converts a number into its appropriate nested tuple:

```
type family NestedTuple (n :: Nat) (a :: *) where
  NestedTuple Z     a = ()
  NestedTuple (S n) a = (a, NestedTuple n a)
```

And finally we can define a function that converts `Vector n a` to its nested tuple form.

```
toList :: Vector n a -> NestedTuple n a
toList Nil = ()
toList (x :- xs) = (x, toList xs)
```

You can test this out at GHCi:

```
ghci> :set -XFlexibleContexts
ghci> toList ("foo" :- "bar" :- "baz" :- Nil)
("foo",("bar",("baz",())))
```